# Where can I find data with cities, districts, towns of each country?

Tags: allocation, administrative

Where can I find data with cities, districts, towns of each country? 
It can be paid service. It must include latitude and longitude.

I checked a few websites and they don't have precise information.

Comment: Do you mean just to see it or do you mean procedurally, like to include them in your code or something?

Comment: @Sterconium i want to include it in my db. But data can be in any format. It`s not so important.